# Can I call an external script within a spreadsheet script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have multiple spreadsheets with the same script in them, and whenever I update it I need to do it in all of them, so is it possible to have the main script stored externally and call it from each spreadsheet to avoid copying and pasting it in them? The script runs in each spreadsheet by using buttons and a custom menu, so the idea is to link those buttons to the main script.

Comment: You can put the project key of an Apps Script project into any other Apps Script project.  It's called a "library."  All it is, is a way for one Apps Script project to access a separate Apps Script project.  It's a good idea to make the Apps Script project that will be the library as a stand alone file.  (Not bound to a Sheet)  From the code editor, choose "Help" and then "documentation" and search "Libraries."

Comment: @SandyGood That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Alternately, deploy an add-on. Then you need only activate it in any sheet of yours, and don't need to write any stubs to use the script in each new spreadsheet.

Comment: @SandyGood I have a new problem, the library works just fine for me but other users get an error, I have made some tests and determined that the solution to this is to share the script with _edit_ authorization and I would rather not share it like this to avoid any future problems. Do you know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: When you get an error, click the View menu item from the code editor, and look at the Execution Transcript.  Does it say what line of code the error occurred on?  We need to see the line of code, and know what the error message it.